# What is the difference between Boost.Context fiber and continuation?

Tags: c++, boost, fibers

Boost.Context provides two mechanisms for switching contexts:

1. `fiber` -  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/ff.html
2. `continuation` - https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/cc.html

These documentation pages have almost the same wordings for both mechanisms and examples are basically the same code with seemingly non-significant API changes.

Are there any conceptual differences between these two mechanisms? And if yes, when to use what?

Comment: I also wonder too. Have you known the differences already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `fiber` supersedes `continuation`, as the [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0876r0.pdf) says:

> This paper addresses concerns, questions and suggestions from the past meetings. The proposed API supersedes the former proposals N3985, P0099R1 and P0534R3.

The P0534R3 is the very proposal for `continuation`.

> Because of name clashes with coroutine from coroutine TS, execution context from executor proposals and continuation used in the context of future::then(), fiber, as suggested by some committee members, has been chosen - filament, tasklet,lightfiber or coop_task are possible alternative names.

So, I think `fiber` is all the same with `continuation` except for the name.

By the way, there's a small difference between the examples for them in the documentation:

```cpp
namespace ctx=boost::context;
int i=1;
ctx::fiber f1{[&i](ctx::fiber&& f2){
    std::printf("inside f1,i==%d\n",i);
    i+=1;
    return std::move(f2).resume();
}};
f1=std::move(f1).resume();
std::printf("i==%d\n",i);

output:
    inside c1,i==1
    i==2
```

```cpp
namespace ctx=boost::context;
int i=1;
ctx::continuation c1=callcc([&i](ctx::continuation && c2){
            std::printf("inside c1,i==%d\n",i);
            i+=1;
            return c2.resume();
        });
std::printf("i==%d\n",i);

output:
    inside c1,i==1
    i==2
```

It seems that `callcc` automatically start the `continuation`, while `fiber` needs to be start manually later.

Here is the current status of the proposal: https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/117 .